# Spring boot oauth2 - How to catch the event just before redirect to the client with token

Tags: spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I am developing an Spring boot app following its oauth stantards. I was wondering if it is possible to catch some event just before the redirection to the client with the valid token.

I need this to include some extra info in the response. That would be possible? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In order to add add extra info on the token a better and more standard way is use the TokenEnhancer. It is an interface that give you the possibility of enhancing an access token before it is stored. I provide you a skeleton example below:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
class SecurityOAuth2AutorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.....
                .tokenEnhancer(tokenEnhancer())
                .approvalStoreDisabled();
    }




    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
        ....
    }


    @Bean
    public TokenEnhancer tokenEnhancer(){
        return new YourTokenEnhancer ();
    }
}

class YourTokenEnhancer implements TokenEnhancer {
    @Override
    public OAuth2AccessToken enhance(OAuth2AccessToken accessToken, OAuth2Authentication authentication) {
        User user = (User) authentication.getPrincipal();
        final Map<String, Object> additionalInfo = new HashMap<>();

        additionalInfo.put("yourAdditionalKey", "yourAdditionalValue");

        ((DefaultOAuth2AccessToken) accessToken).setAdditionalInformation(additionalInfo);

        return accessToken;
    }
}
```

Update

considering your message if you want add info in an header you can use an interceptor and bind to the org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint class that is the class that you invoke for retrieve the token and add hear the your extra information.

However I discourage this approach in favor of a more standard way and consider to use the TokenEnhancer that is the standard way for add extra info on your token.

**Update**

considering the comments I can suggest to implements your audit logic with an aspect in your authentication server the aspect can be like below:

```
@Aspect
@Component
class AuditLogger {

    @AfterReturning("execution(* org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint.postAccessToken(..))")
    public void aspect(JoinPoint joinPoint)  {
        Map<String, String> params = (Map<String, String>) joinPoint.getArgs()[1];
        System.out.println("success");
        System.out.println(params);
//        your audit logic in case of successful login
    }

    @AfterThrowing(value = "execution(* org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint.postAccessToken(..))", throwing = "error")
    public void error(JoinPoint joinPoint, Exception error) {
        System.out.println(error);
        Map<String, String> params = (Map<String, String>) joinPoint.getArgs()[1];
        System.out.println("error");
        System.out.println(params);
//        your audit logic in case of failure login
    }

}
```

I suggest to use an aspect instead of implements custom components of spring security because: first of all, audit is a cross cutting concern and an aspect is one of the best solution to achieve this and then, because customize Spring Security, especially for Oauth2, is a challeng and i do not advice it, in my experience is too complex and the effort do not repay the effort, the protocol is very complex and fill all use cases is a challenge. With an aspect that do the audit for you in he correct point is the best option for you.

I built an aspect that do audit on the `TokenEndpoint.postAccessToken` method, that is the code of Spring security oAuht2 that generate the token

The code of your interest in the Spring framework is  below:

```
@FrameworkEndpoint
public class TokenEndpoint extends AbstractEndpoint {

    ....

    @RequestMapping(value = "/oauth/token", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<OAuth2AccessToken> postAccessToken(Principal principal, @RequestParam
            Map<String, String> parameters) throws HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException {

        if (!(principal instanceof Authentication)) {
            throw new InsufficientAuthenticationException(
                    "There is no client authentication. Try adding an appropriate authentication filter.");
        }

        String clientId = getClientId(principal);
        ClientDetails authenticatedClient = getClientDetailsService().loadClientByClientId(clientId);

        TokenRequest tokenRequest = getOAuth2RequestFactory().createTokenRequest(parameters, authenticatedClient);

        if (clientId != null && !clientId.equals("")) {
            // Only validate the client details if a client authenticated during this
            // request.
            if (!clientId.equals(tokenRequest.getClientId())) {
                // double check to make sure that the client ID in the token request is the same as that in the
                // authenticated client
                throw new InvalidClientException("Given client ID does not match authenticated client");
            }
        }
        if (authenticatedClient != null) {
            oAuth2RequestValidator.validateScope(tokenRequest, authenticatedClient);
        }
        if (!StringUtils.hasText(tokenRequest.getGrantType())) {
            throw new InvalidRequestException("Missing grant type");
        }
        if (tokenRequest.getGrantType().equals("implicit")) {
            throw new InvalidGrantException("Implicit grant type not supported from token endpoint");
        }

        if (isAuthCodeRequest(parameters)) {
            // The scope was requested or determined during the authorization step
            if (!tokenRequest.getScope().isEmpty()) {
                logger.debug("Clearing scope of incoming token request");
                tokenRequest.setScope(Collections.<String> emptySet());
            }
        }

        if (isRefreshTokenRequest(parameters)) {
            // A refresh token has its own default scopes, so we should ignore any added by the factory here.
            tokenRequest.setScope(OAuth2Utils.parseParameterList(parameters.get(OAuth2Utils.SCOPE)));
        }

        OAuth2AccessToken token = getTokenGranter().grant(tokenRequest.getGrantType(), tokenRequest);
        if (token == null) {
            throw new UnsupportedGrantTypeException("Unsupported grant type: " + tokenRequest.getGrantType());
        }

        return getResponse(token);

    }

    ....
}
```

I hope that it can help you

Comment: Thanks for the reply!! Token enhancer is cool but I need to add a header in the final response when the token is sent. So I thing I need the HttpServletResponse as parameter in somewhere. Do you know how can I do it?

Comment: And there is no way to set a filter at the end just to inject a cookie in the response? It is not a header is a cookie. I explained that wrong. If I develop my custom authenticationsuccess I cannot redirect to the point that I want with the token (does not continue the flow)

Comment: ............ in my experience if is not street necessary i discourage it because the not standard way many times create more problem that solution

Comment: Yeah I get it you are right. Nevertheless, Do you know if there is a possibility to capture the event when the user is successfully logged in via login form? I've tried with a custom auth success but the problem is the redirection. (I want this to keep an access log. successful or failed attemps)

Comment: do you want log  successful or failed attemps on the auth server log? ..... I Hope if it is I will update my answer considering it

Comment: in the Database. The thing is if I implement the successful handler and I save the successful attempt I don't know how to perform the redirection. Is there any better way to save success/failed logins? Maybe directly in the AuthenticationProvider?

Comment: I had updated my answer in my opinion is the best solution for, I hope that it can solve your problems